# Building a Chess Board with Particles

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collision

[image]I'd like to create an animation of squares falling down (1) to form a chess board.

The squares would be falling in sequence and once at field level a chess part will emerge from it resizing from 0% to 100% (2) and (3).

So, here's my question:

I'm currently animating square by square and part by part. Is there an easier way?
I was thinking maybe particles or solid bodies would help...

I've seen tutorials where you can model/animate a group of objects and then use particles to populate a world, but so far I've only seen random worlds, nothing as structured as a chess board (8x8 squares). If I use rigid bodies and let the squares fall all of them fall at once and once they hit the ground they bounce a bit so it does not look perfect.

What would you do? is this a 100% manual task?

Comment: Sounds perfect for Python if you have a bit of scripting experience.

Comment: Thanks @jakeD, no programming experience at all. So there's no native, out of the box solution you think?

Comment: I don't think so, but someone may know a clever "artist-friendly" solution. Never say never.

Comment: Not an expert at it but also sounds like something Animation Nodes could do easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animation Nodes can be used here. *Grid Mesh Node* can be used to create the grid. Move the grid $10$ units upward and offset the polygons by $-10$ using the *Offset Polygons Node* and use a falloff of your choice, I am assuming you want a *Delay Falloff*.

[image: Delay Falloff]

Similarly, you can scale some instances of an object to get the scaling effect. The same *Delay Falloff* can be used, but you will have to delay it using the *Delay Time Node* so that the object starts scaling after its corresponding grid cell has been positioned.

[image: Scale Objects]

Answer (score 4):

The falling grid is quite easy to do with particles :

*I forgot some things in the original answer, added them in emphasis*

- add a Grid object with 9x9 subdivisions (= 8x8 faces) *(Not strictly necessary, a simple Plane works as well)*
- add a ParticleSystem on it with Grid distribution, render Unborn, Died, no Emitter. *Choose a Grid Resolution of 8.*
- create a object for your tile, and add it as a Dupli Object for your Psys. Adjust his Size.
- create a Plane somewhere under your emitter, and in Physics enable Collision ; check Kill Particles.

[image]

The falling effect is working but all the tiles have the same color. To avoid that, you can give them a material like this one :

[image]

The Checker texture use the texture coordinates of the Grid object ; otherwise, the checker will apply on each individual Tile object.

The mapping node "kills" the Z component of the coordinates ; otherwise, the tiles will change color while falling (as their Z coordinate changes). *Change X and Y Scale to 0.8 match the pattern of the tiles*